# How to create a stack of cards with UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, animation

The final effect what I want to achieve is this:

[Click this link](https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/692322/screenshots/3731362/dribbble.gif)

I did not know what to choose for that, UICollectionView or to create custom UIView? Later decided to choose UICollectionView.

The result what I got is:

[image]

For this effect, I used this code:

```
if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = -200.0
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 30.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 30.0)
    }
```

and

```
cell.layer.zPosition = -CGFloat(indexPath.row)
```

to put them one under another one. Also, I checked "Paging Enabled" checkbox.

But the problem is:

I cannot scroll them now and I think it's because of `layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = -200.0`. When I scroll, all 3 cards scroll together.

How can I achieve the effect in the URL? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have to use collection view?

Comment: @YunusErenGüzel no, I just preferred to use it. It's not "must use"

Comment: @agibson007 I forgot, sorry :)

Comment: I am pretty sure that I can implement this easily without a collection view.  I have two of these that work pretty similar in production.  Give me some time to look up the code unless someone jumps on this before I get it.  You can find a lot of examples like this https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda  an another https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeCards. Although these are to the same they are a good roadmap.  Although the swipe back might be easier with a collectionview

Comment: How would the user know that they can swipe back the view that goes out left?  Just curious.

Comment: @J.Doe did you manage to do this? I’ve a similar problem, I think collection view is the right tool for the job, what did you use in the end?

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/PushpaCollectionViewLayout